# C#.NET create WMV file from JPEG images

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a set of JPEG images. I want to create wmv files from jpeg images with C#. How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you willing to pay or want something just for free?

Comment: What about searching google for - "create video from jpeg c#"

Comment: Little harsh guys, don't you think? 5 downvotes is a tad excessive.

Comment: If you re-ask this question, please show what work you have done, what code you have written, what research you have done.

Comment: what is wrong with this question. i have a set of images and i want to create a wmv file out of that with the help of c# code. I want a free solution. I have searched it for , i guess you people also didn't get a proper end to this. thats why the question has been marked as closed right? Enjoy the free points

Comment: You guys didnt try to understand the question. I guess this is the way you are getting reputation points from the others when you dont know the answer. 
Check this link, the same question has been asked over here http://www.ureader.com/msg/13896.aspx

Comment: You guys didnt try to understand the question. I guess this is the way you are getting reputation points from the others when you dont know the answer. 
Check this link, the same question has been asked over here http://www.ureader.com/msg/13896.aspx
on the above link, the people who are answering the question had no any such problem as you guys have.They atleast tried to answer the question. Seriously uff, i had a very bad experience with the stackoverflow just because of you 5 people. Perhaps i will be using this forum in future. Codeproject is far better than you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way will be to use a third party library like [Bytescout Image To Video SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/imagetovideosdk/imagetovideosdk_convert_jpg_to_video.html).

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel N for your answer. This is one of the solutions available, but i am looking for a free solution right now.